# Traffic Light system for warranties in a MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table of printers with a warranty start and warrant end date stored as a date field in our MYSQL database

I want to visualise the warranty end dates using the current date as a traffic lights system

- Red - warranties ended
- Amber - warranties ending within 90 days
- Green - warranties that end in more than 90 days

Example data

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|                  id                  | warrantystart_c | warrantyend_c |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
| 001c28c4-b9cf-11e9-88a2-020683bef092 | 2018-07-13      | 2020-07-12    |
| 453b9ba2-b9ce-11e9-8fd6-0265ed7510c2 | 2018-09-26      | 2020-09-25    |
| 5c8353e2-0585-11ea-bbe5-066c2def7d44 | 2018-09-26      | 2020-09-25    |
| 71F1934                              | 2018-08-28      | 2020-08-27    |
| 71F1936                              | 2018-08-28      | 2020-08-27    |
| 71F2367                              | 2018-09-03      | 2020-09-02    |
| 001c28c4-b9cf-11e9-88a2-020683bef092 | 2018-07-13      | 2020-07-12    |
| 0024d2ca-fb2f-11e9-8fcc-0265ed7510c2 | 2019-08-20      | 2022-08-19    |
| 00514c1c-6a5a-11e9-9026-0265ed7510c2 | 2019-04-18      | 2022-04-17    |
| 00613772-bdc4-11e9-8c8f-0265ed7510c2 | 2019-07-01      | 2022-06-30    |
| 006ac524-ef5d-11e9-b323-020683bef092 | 2019-09-30      | 2022-09-29    |
| 006b3ea2-e911-11e9-8ab6-0265ed7510c2 | 2019-10-07      | 2022-10-06    |
| 008fb146-f501-11e9-9875-06a63d65978a | 2018-02-14      | 2021-02-13    |
| 0130078c-d2ff-11e9-96e7-06a63d65978a | 2019-08-23      | 2022-08-22    |
| 0180c41e-bf5a-11e9-8abf-06a63d65978a | 2019-07-25      | 2022-07-24    |
| 0279f4ce-bdc2-11e9-ac0d-020683bef092 | 2019-07-01      | 2022-06-30    |
| 002f826c-c7cf-11e9-9104-0265ed7510c2 | NULL            | 1969-12-31    |
| 031b46b4-113f-11ea-80e4-020683bef092 | 2014-07-10      | 2017-07-09    |
| 0af91f74-52da-11e9-947b-0265ed7510c2 | 2019-04-01      | 2019-04-30    |
| 0c89a096-f5bb-11e9-9313-066c2def7d44 | 1900-01-02      | 1905-01-01    |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

from this table the result I'm looking to get is

```
+-----+-------+-------+--+
| Red | amber | green |  |
+-----+-------+-------+--+
|   4 |     6 |    10 |  |
+-----+-------+-------+--+
```

I have tried three WHERE clauses to get this data

```
snc.warrantyend_c < current_date // Red
snc.warrantyend_c BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) // Amber
snc.warrantyend_c > subdate(current_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY) // Green
```

I just wandered if there's a better way to do the where clauses  and an efficient way to do this all in one query or should I use sub queries?

Comment: Sub queries would work.  Otherwise you could use the last where clause and 3  Case statements to set a Red, Amber and Green Column to 0 or 1 which you then sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that your existing individual queries will get you the data you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as red FROM warrantiesWHERE end < current_date;
SELECT COUNT(*) as yellow FROM warranties WHERE end BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY);
SELECT COUNT(*) as green FROM warrantiesWHERE end > subdate(current_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

But these can be combined with a CASE statement as a separate column:

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN end < current_date THEN 'red'
    WHEN end BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 'yellow'
    WHEN end > subdate(current_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 'green'
  END as color
FROM warranties;
```

And then finally you can use GROUP BY on this query to get the counts:

```
SELECT
  color,
  COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN end < current_date THEN 'red'
      WHEN end BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 'yellow'
      WHEN end > subdate(current_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 'green'
    END as color
  FROM warranties
  ) colors
  GROUP BY color;
```

Working example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aed6cd/2

Comment: thank you @WOUNDEDStevenJones I've found some learning resources on cases so I can use these more instead of sub queries and make my sql more efficient Cheers for the examples too

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate and `sum()` the expressions for the different colors. This works as Boolean expressions in numeric context are interpreted as `1` for true and `0` for false in MySQL.

```
SELECT sum(snc.warrantyend_c < current_date) red,
       sum(snc.warrantyend_c BETWEEN current_date and date_add(current_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)) amber,
       sum(snc.warrantyend_c > subdate(current_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)) green
       FROM elbat snc;
```

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones: Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for you help and I'm working through some lessons to learn more about the points raised. I've used this to create the full statement

```
SELECT
  color,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT
        sn.id,
    CASE
        WHEN snc.warrantyend_c < current_date THEN 'red'
        WHEN snc.warrantyend_c BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 'amber'
        WHEN snc.warrantyend_c > subdate(current_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 'green'
    END AS color
    FROM
        s_serialnumber sn
        LEFT JOIN s_serialnumber_cstm snc ON sn.id = snc.id_c
    WHERE
        snc.dealer_id_c = "1000521"     
) colors
GROUP BY color;
```